# Problem with GIMP when instaling scangearmp on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gimp

I get the following message when installing scangermp on ubuntu, i run the command ./autogen.sh and then i get :

*checking for GIMP... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gimp-2.0 >= 2.0.0) were not met:
No package 'gimp-2.0' found
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GIMP_CFLAGS
and GIMP_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.*

gimp is installed. But  i don't find gimp2

Thank for any help on this matter.

Comment: Can you run the command `dpkg -l | grep gimp` and add the results to your post please?

Answer (score 6):

The *gimp* packages does not contain the files necessary to compile other software against it. On Ubuntu the the files needed for using some software and the files needed for development and compilation are in separate packages. In order to fulfill the requirements for compilation you need to install the *dev*-packages for the dependencies.

In the case of gimp this should be the package named `libgimp2.0-dev`.

```
apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev
```

Comment: However i get another error when compiling :

Comment: @maat it is likely that there are more development packages missing. The procedure is the same.

Comment: However i get another error when compiling :  
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I. -I./include -DV_MAJOR=2 -DV_MINOR=1 -O2 -D__GIMP_PLUGIN_ENABLE__ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MT libsane_canon_mfp_la-canon_mfp.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libsane_canon_mfp_la-canon_mfp.Tpo -c canon_mfp.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libsane_canon_mfp_la-canon_mfp.o
canon_mfp.c:47:23: fatal error: sane/sane.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sane/sane.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: probably but i can find the packages...